# Unnest list into two separate columns

Tags: r, tidyverse

I want to unnest a list into two separate columns using tidyverse syntax like the `mutate` function.

For example:

```
data %>% mutate_at("centroid", unnest_wider)
```

Gives me the following error:

> x Argument `col` is missing with no default

I have tried assigning column names using

```
.cols=c("X", "Y")
```

In the code but I still get the error.

Example data:

```
data <- structure(list(disasterno = c("2009-0631", "2009-0631", "2001-0146", 
"2009-0092", "2009-0092", "2009-0092"), centroid = structure(list(
    structure(c(19.4183172957388, 42.0209484621449), class = c("XY", 
    "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(19.5143087402113, 41.9592941221655
    ), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(15.6657576094231, 
    -17.093484362207), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(15.7739867740437, 
    -16.5315326589011), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(15.7739867740437, 
    -16.5315326589011), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(15.7739867740437, 
    -16.5315326589011), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POINT", 
"sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 15.6657576094231, 
ymin = -17.093484362207, xmax = 19.5143087402113, ymax = 42.0209484621449
), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(input = "EPSG:4326", 
    wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n    DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic latitude (Lat)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic longitude (Lon)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Horizontal component of 3D system.\"],\n        AREA[\"World.\"],\n        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please provide example input data (the list you want to work with).

Answer (score 1):

```
> data %>% tidyr::unnest_wider(centroid)
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  disasterno  ...1  ...2
  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>
1 2009-0631   19.4  42.0
2 2009-0631   19.5  42.0
3 2001-0146   15.7 -17.1
4 2009-0092   15.8 -16.5
5 2009-0092   15.8 -16.5
6 2009-0092   15.8 -16.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, based on `tidyr::separate`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  separate(centroid, into = c("cent1", "cent2"), sep=", ") %>% 
  mutate(across(2:3, ~ parse_number(.)))

#>   disasterno    cent1     cent2
#> 1  2009-0631 19.41832  42.02095
#> 2  2009-0631 19.51431  41.95929
#> 3  2001-0146 15.66576 -17.09348
#> 4  2009-0092 15.77399 -16.53153
#> 5  2009-0092 15.77399 -16.53153
#> 6  2009-0092 15.77399 -16.53153
```